# Why is this vector of vectors out of scope?

Tags: c++

I've written the code below to add/multiply a vector of vectors (a multidimensional array, essentially):

```
int matrix_numbers[] = { 1, 2 };

// get rows and columns from user (omitted)

for each (int matrix in matrix_numbers) {
  if (matrix == 1) {
      vector<vector<int>> first_matrix(rows, vector<int>(columns));
      request_matrix_data(first_matrix, rows, columns);
      output_matrix_data(first_matrix, rows, columns);
  }
  else { // matrix == 2
      vector<vector<int>> second_matrix(rows, vector<int>(columns));
      request_matrix_data(second_matrix, rows, columns);
      output_matrix_data(second_matrix, rows, columns);
  }
}

add_them(first_matrix, second_matrix);
```

I'm getting the following errors from Visual Studio for the `add_them()` function:

```
error C2065: 'first_matrix': undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'second_matrix': undeclared identifier
```

I can tell from the debugger that `first_matrix` and `second_matrix` are being dumped after the `for each` loop, but why is that?

Comment: `for each (int matrix in matrix_numbers)` -- Is this C++?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, [Yes*, but it's not a good idea](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/for-each-in?view=vs-2019).

Comment: *but why is that?* -- Thank goodness that C++ has `scoping rules`, where objects are destroyed once leaving scope.  Otherwise C++ would be even a more difficult language to use correctly.  Also, the issue has nothing to do with vectors -- if you declared a simple `int` within the `{ }`, you would have had the same errors.

Comment: @chris - actually, it is a non-standard (Microsoft) extension.

Comment: @Peter, That is true as well. That's why I put the star in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are declaring them within the if statement inside the for loop.
This means you can only access them within that if statement.
See this tutorial on [variable scope](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm)

You can fix them by rewriting them to have a scope equal to the function.

Your iterator also looks wrong, you should rewrite this also.

```
const int matrix_size = 2;
int matrix_numbers[matrix_size] = { 1, 2 };

vector<vector<int>> first_matrix;
vector<vector<int>> second_matrix;

// get rows and columns from user (omitted)

for (int n = 0; n < matrix_size; n ++) {
  int matrix = matrix_numbers[n];

  if (matrix == 1) {
      first_matrix = vector<vector<int>>(rows, vector<int>(columns));
      request_matrix_data(first_matrix, rows, columns);
      output_matrix_data(first_matrix, rows, columns);
  }
  else { // matrix == 2
      second_matrix = vector<vector<int>>(rows, vector<int>(columns));
      request_matrix_data(second_matrix, rows, columns);
      output_matrix_data(second_matrix, rows, columns);
  }
}

add_them(first_matrix, second_matrix);
```

Comment: Perfect! That was it. Thank you so much :)